# Space or tabs as separator in CSV

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I usually put "sep=," or "sep=;" as first line on my csv files so i can easily open them with excel. But is there a way to use this with space and tab separated files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`"sep=/t"` for tab delimited

`"sep= "` for space delimited, should work

Comment: I actually never used ", so this did not seem to work for the space issue until i literally typed the quotes.

Comment: Is it a part of CSV standard or custom Excel thing?

Comment: @BogdanGusiev I'm pretty sure this is part of the way excel processes csv files, but I've never found any documentation on it. [see here](http://superuser.com/questions/773644/what-is-the-sep-metadata-you-can-add-to-csvs)